# Is the function defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{10^n}$ if $x \in(2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}) $ integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is the function $$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{10^n},  & \text{if $x$ }\in(2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}) \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}, f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$$ 
integrable? I am not sure how to show that. Should I use some theorem? One way or another I would have to show that conditions are fulfilled, but I am not sure which. I would really appreciate your help.

Besides, how can I find $\int_0^{1}f$, i.e, how can I take care of the problematic part, 0?

Comment: Hint for integrability: $f$ is non-decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}10^n}.$$